# `case_when()` passes NA through when !=

Tags: r, dplyr, na, equality

I am trying to create a new column that indicates differences between two existing columns. `NA`s should be considered values and should be marked as "difference". However, `NA`s are being "passed through" the `!=` comparator. I have looked for `case_when` arguments to deal with `NA`s and looked for alternative not equal comparators to no avail.

The below reprex shows the current output and the desired output.

Thank you in advance for your help!

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)

df <- 
  expand_grid(x = c("a", NA), y = c("b", NA)) %>% 
  add_row(x = "a", y = "a") %>% 
  add_row(x = "b", y = "b")

df
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>   x     y    
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 a     b    
#> 2 a     <NA> 
#> 3 <NA>  b    
#> 4 <NA>  <NA> 
#> 5 a     a    
#> 6 b     b

# Non-desired output: NA's passed through instead of treated as values
  df %>% 
  mutate(z = case_when(
    x == "a" & y == "a" ~ "a",
    x == "b" &  y == "b" ~ "b",
    x != y ~ "difference"
  ))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   x     y     z         
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>     
#> 1 a     b     difference
#> 2 a     <NA>  <NA>      
#> 3 <NA>  b     <NA>      
#> 4 <NA>  <NA>  <NA>      
#> 5 a     a     a         
#> 6 b     b     b

# Desired output
  df %>% 
  add_column(z = c(rep("difference", 3), NA_character_, "a", "b"))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   x     y     z         
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>     
#> 1 a     b     difference
#> 2 a     <NA>  difference
#> 3 <NA>  b     difference
#> 4 <NA>  <NA>  <NA>      
#> 5 a     a     a         
#> 6 b     b     b
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: You can use `is.na` as `==` returns NA whenever there is a NA

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with `==` and `NA`.  Any value compared to NA returns `NA`.  It can be corrected with `is.na` also in the comparison, but then it needs to be repeated.  Or else an easy fix is to change the `NA` to a different value, do the comparison and bind with the original dataset

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   mutate(across(x:y, replace_na, '')) %>%
   transmute(z = case_when(
    x == "a" & y == "a" ~ "a",
    x == "b" &  y == "b" ~ "b",
    x != y ~ "difference"
    )) %>%
   bind_cols(df, .)
```

Comment: Thanks, Akrun! I also worked something out with `is.na` as you indicated. I'll post that too in case it's of use to someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Like @akrun mentioned, there's a workaround with `is.na` with "exclusive or"/`xor`. Here's what I ended up using:

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(z = case_when(
    x == y ~ x,
    xor(is.na(x), is.na(y)) ~ "difference",
    x != y ~ "difference",
    is.na(x) & is.na(y) ~ NA_character_
  ))
```